# Magento 2.3 & pwa studio: How can I access another store to update data or get data other than that of the default store? Is it possible?

Tags: magento2, graphql, pwa-studio

The store is composed of different websites with multiple stores and multiple storeviews.

I'm developing a functionality to get the particular storeview depending on the location of the customer and get its product catalog with prices.

But when I go to get the information from the current store I am always in the default store using GraphQL query,

- **How could I get the information from any other store or set values in a different store?**
- **Is there a GraphQl query or can I make a request to the Rest API to change store to get the products from a store using the store id or store code?**

Answer (score 5):

> **GraphQL request accepts the Store into headers.**

```
Header Key : Store

Header Value : <store_view_code>
```

**The store view code on which to perform the request. The value can be default or the code that is defined when a store view is created.**

[image]

*I recommend you to use [Altair GraphQL Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/altair-graphql-client/flnheeellpciglgpaodhkhmapeljopja?hl=en)*

[For More Header click Here](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/webapi/graphql/usage/headers/#request-headers)

***I Hope This Helps You.***

Comment: Not sure why they can't do this in the code, 2.4.4 still has this problem

Comment: @DavidTay If you need it so please rise issue in Magento github.

Answer (score 4):

For Storewise Graphql queries you need to add a variable in HEADER just like AUTHORIZATION in Magento 2 . The Header for Store wise data is

Store:

for more Information you can check 
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/graphql/send-request.html#headers

Answer (score 1):

I had a setup where one magento backend was used for two magento websites each with at least a store and a store_view. For me it was loading the same default store even though I had changed the `MAGENTO_BACKEND_URL` value.

In order to fix that I had to add the required `STORE_VIEW_CODE` in .env file under venia-concept in order to load the desired store.

For more information

https://magento.github.io/pwa-studio/pwa-buildpack/reference/environment-variables/core-definitions/

Answer (score 0):

> Header Key and Value for postman graphql
>
> ```
> // enter header key as 'Store' and value as store code e.g ar
> Store - ar
>
> // enter header key as 'content-currency' and value as store code e.g AED
> content-currency - AED
> ```

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Resolver;

use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Config\Element\Field;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Exception\GraphQlInputException;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Exception\GraphQlAuthorizationException;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Query\ResolverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Schema\Type\ResolveInfo;

class ExampleClass implements ResolverInterface
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function resolve(
        Field $field,
        $context,
        ResolveInfo $info,
        array $value = null,
        array $args = null
    ) {
        // get store and currency from graphql
        $store = $context->getExtensionAttributes()->getStore();
        $currency = $store->getCurrentCurrencyCode();
        $store = $store->getCode();

        $data = $offer->getData();
        $data['model'] = $offer;

        return ['offer' => 'test data'];
    }
}
```