# Magento 2.4.6p2 graphql customer token

Tags: multistore, customer-account, multi-website, magento-graphql

I have a multi site Magento installation we do not share login per website.
We have 2 websites under the same domain each with separate store views.

If you create and account on the second store view I'm enabled to via graphql login customer using generateCustomerToken. Am I missing something this doesn't work?

```
mutation generateCustomerToken($email: String!, $password: String!) {
      generateCustomerToken(email: $email, password: $password) {
      token
  }
}
```

Error:

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "The account sign-in was incorrect or your account is disabled temporarily. Please wait and try again later.",
            "locations": [
                {
                    "line": 2,
                    "column": 7
                }
            ],
            "path": [
                "generateCustomerToken"
            ],
            "extensions": {
                "category": "graphql-authentication"
            }
        }
    ],
    "data": {
        "generateCustomerToken": null
    }
}
```

However I can login fine via the website store view url.

Comment: Hi, which version of Magento 2 you are using? You might be looking for [link ] (https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/35084) and one PR was raised against this issue [link] (https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/98557ac646c91e180b9a11b3d3b64a4d839b98cc). If it is the same issue then you can create a custom patch from the PR and apply it.

Comment: I just checked the fix is available in v2.4.6-p2

Comment: just a quick question. Are you passing the store code in the header? If not then it could be the possible reason for this issue.

Answer (score 1):

> **Yes, you have to create customer tokens for different stores on the website.**

**First, you need to add a store in the header and create a token for the customer. So every customer token is created by the current store in the header. If you did not add a store in your header then it's take default store.**

> For Add Store in header please check this link : https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/326128/82670

[image]

Comment: ahhh ok I need to add the header 'Store' Thanks, I found the docs where this is mentioned : https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/graphql/send-request.html#headers 
 But not here https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/webapi/graphql/schema/customer/mutations/generate-token/

Comment: However it works, there seems to be an issue when switching between store sometimes I get `The account sign-in was incorrect or your account is disabled temporarily. Please wait and try again later.` After waiting like 30min or so I requested again and it worked, I'm using postman for testing and I could login with the same credentials via the frontend but Graphql seem to have some issue. I'll got this issue couple of times where I had to wait, I'll try and replicate to see If I can find what's causing it